# Multi monitor setup with a tv as well?

Tags: multiple-monitors, tv, hdtv

I have always had a dual monitor setup for my pc's for years now.  I am now in the market to build a new PC and get some new stuff.

I need some help or advice on how to run 3 monitors WITH a 4th display which will be a lcd/plasma tv.

So I am thinking I can get 2 video cards and that will give me all the hookups to run 3 monitors instead of 2.  I will mount all 3 monitors in a row side by side and above them on the wall I would like to mount a larger 30-40+ inch lcd or plasma tv.  I would then like to hook up my atelite/cable to this tv just as I would normally hook up a tv but I would like to also be able to have an option to view my PC o this tv as well.  I know that is possible but would it be possible to view my PC on that tv and also still view my 3 other monitors and have the TV be a 4th display, where I could dock a different app/window in windows in all 4 displays (3 monitors + tv) ??

Please tell me any tips/advice on how to do this including what cables/software if any/converters/ you name it.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is doable. Most new TVs these days have one of HDMI, DVI, or VGA inputs. Video cards generally have DVI or VGA outputs (some top of the line ones also have HDMI). It's easy to convert from DVI to HDMI, or from DVI to VGA with a cheap (under $5) converter. So I recommend getting two video cards that each have 2 DVI out ports. Make sure you get a motherboard for your PC that can support two video cards, some of the lowend ones will only support a single graphics card.

Comment: The thing I am confused about, I need for the tv to only show the PC on it when I want it to, other times it would just show my cable/satelite, any ideas?

Comment: You just use your TV remote to switch inputs. The 'PC' will be connected to one input, your cable to another input, your DVD player to another input, etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Windows (if it's the OS you are using) supports extending the desktop to three monitors. I know it supports extending it to two monitors (I use it everyday), but I have never tried 3 or more.

Comment: It supports as many as your video card / drivers support. 4 is no problem (the asker wants 4 total monitors, counting the tv, not just 3).